# Marginal distribution limits

Tags: limits

Q1. Consider the joint density of X and Y given by
f(x,y) = (e^(−y))/y 
when 0 < x < y < ∞ and 0 elsewhere.
(a) Derive and identify the marginal distribution of Y

I am not sure if the limits are used are correct. I integrated with respect to x between the limits of y and 0. Is this correct

Comment: "I integrated with respect to x between the limits of y and 0. Is this correct" Indeed, for every $y>0$, the integral with respect to $x$ is over the interval $(0,y)$. Is this your question?

Comment: yeah thats what i was thinking it was